# Multivariable ODE with linear and quadratic terms

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $z(t):\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R^n$ satisfies the ODE $$\frac{dz}{dt}=Az+\sum_k (C_kz)\odot(C_kz)$$ for matrices $A,C_1,\ldots,C_m\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. Here $\odot$ denotes the Hadamard product.

**Is there any hope of writing a closed form solution for $z(t)$?**

In one dimension it seems the standard integrating factors trick works, but I’m not sure how to generalize.

Comment: Is there any assumption about the matrices $A,C_1,\ldots,C_m$?

Comment: I'm trying to solve a problem related to yours in 1D.  Your comment "In one dimension it seems the standard integrating factors trick works, but I’m not sure how to generalize" is enticing.  Could you share some details about how to do this in 1D?